# Python and MySQL - which to use more?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm using matplotlib and MySQLdb to create some graphs from a MySQL database. For example, the number of unique visitors in a given time period, grouped by periods of say, 1 hours. So, there'll be a bunch of (Time, visits in 1-hour period near that time) points.

I have a table as (ip, visit_time) where each ip can occur multiple times.

My question is should I run a single query and then process the results (remove duplicates, do the counting etc.), or should I run multiple SQL queries (for example, for 1 day period, there will be 24 queries for finding out the number of visits in each hour). Which will be faster and more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally Database queries should be faster than python for two reasons:

1. Databases are optimised to work with data, and they will optimise a high level abstraction language like SQL in order to get the best performance, while python might be fast but doesn't have to be
2. Running SQL analyses the data at the source and you don't need to transfer it at first.

That being said, there might be some extremely complex queries which could be faster in python but this doesn't seem the case for your. Also the more you squash the data with sql the smaller and easier the algorithm in python will be.

At last, I don't know your queries, but it should be possible to run them for all 24h at once including the removing duplicates and counting.

Comment: How would I run them at once? So far I'm using something like "SELECT DISTINCT ip, visit_time FROM visits_table WHERE visit_time BETWEEN time1 AND time2"

Comment: There is `GROUP BY` and you can have basically almost an infinite amount of subqueries. Also if you don't know how to run them in one query together you can just join the 24 queries with `UNION` - SQL is more powerful than you might think

Comment: But IMO 'GROUP BY' won't help because I need to count by a time period, not the actual time. Can you please give an example query.

Comment: Check this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154170/mysql-group-by-dates-between

Comment: Additionally to @Chococroc example, I've also implemented `GROUP BY` based on a function. But that was in SQL Server so the code in MySQL is going to look different, but you can create (or maybe there is one and you only need to use it) a function which gives you the hour without the minutes. Than you can group by this hour. Additional date can be separately in another column, this way you can group by every hour every day and perform all the counts, ... what you need

Comment: I'm going to stick with this one : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8157754/3551365) I can easily generate the appropriate cases using python.