# How to select array of rows with max param from each range?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have sqlite table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE "table" (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `param` REAL NOT NULL,
    `date`  INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table (param , date) VALUES (123.3, 1427824800 );
INSERT INTO table (param , date) VALUES (122.3, 1427825800 );
INSERT INTO table (param , date) VALUES (125.0, 1427652000 );
INSERT INTO table (param , date) VALUES (123.9, 1427652900);


|id| param | date       |
|==|=======|============|
| 1| 123.3 | 1427824800 |
| 2| 122.3 | 1427825800 |
| 3| 125   | 1427652000 |
| 4| 123.9 | 1427652900 |
```

And get row with max date for each day like(BETWEEN startDay AND endDay) - I need to understand how to group it at least by day, but if there are any way to group via custom period(week, month) it would be great

```
SELECT id, param, MAX(date) FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN 1427652000 AND 1427824799
SELECT id, param, MAX(date) FROM table  WHERE date BETWEEN 1427824800 AND 1427911199
```

But trully I got much more data for nearly  year and 1000+ rows and make 365 queries not an option I think, but I don't know how to optimize it

**UPD**
After all I think it is real to get one query to get result like this:

```
|id| param | date       |
|==|=======|============|
| 2| 122.3 | 1427825800 |
| 4| 123.9 | 1427652900 |
```

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY`? Also, please edit your question to give an example of what results you are expecting.

Comment: What would the desired output look like?

Comment: @rlanvin , trully I don't quiet understand how to group it, is it posible to group via "between"? how?

Comment: @Strawberry , make UPD, tnx

Comment: Results still don't make sense to me. Are you trying to group by day? You said "365 queries" so it seems like it, but I'm sorry I don't read fluently UNIX timestamps, I can't guess your logic.

Comment: sorry, yes between in question works like BETWEEN startDay AND endDay

Comment: Yes I know that, but are you trying to group **by day** (as in "between 2015-08-25 00:00:00 and 2015-08-25 23:59:59"), or is the time period of you group **more** than one day (i.e. 2 days, a week, a month, etc.)?

Comment: @rlanvin for now I need at least for each day, but It would be perfect if there would be opportunity to group for custom period

Comment: Ok so it looks like you need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154170/mysql-group-by-dates-between

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87885/discussion-between-seko-and-rlanvin).

Comment: @rlanvin tnx I checked it before and try again like 
SELECT id, param, max(date) FROM table GROUP BY if(date between 1427652000 and 1427911199, 0, 1) 
And get no such function If 
for sqlite there is "case" try like 
SELECT id, weight, max(date) FROM weight GROUP BY case WHEN date between 1427652000 and 1427911199 then 0 else 1 
without luck 
what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You know that there are 86400 seconds in a day, right?

Comment: @Strawberry as I understand IF(condition, true, else) so write so If(between condition, 0, 1) - as I understand it is for grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you want. You'll use `GROUP BY` and you'll use the [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to extract the day from each item. [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) are helpful for flipping back and forth between the `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` representations.  This is necessary because the date arithmetic stuff works on `DATETIME` values. [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) means today.

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) AS day,
       MAX(`date`) AS latest_timestamp_in_day
  FROM table
 WHERE `date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 366 DAY)
   AND `date` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
 GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))
 ORDER BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) DESC
```

This works because

```
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))
```

takes each timestamp and returns the `DATETIME` value of the first moment of the calendar day in which it falls.

The first `WHERE` clause picks up dates on or after a year and a day ago. The second one excludes today's dates; presumably the MAX operation doesn't make much sense on a not-yet-completed day.

It isn't clear from your question whether you also want to display the `param` value associated with the last timestamp in each calendar day. If you do, that's a little harder. You first need to get the latest timestamp in each day, then you need to pull out the detail record. That requires a join operation. You'll treat the above query as a subquery, and join it to your `table`. Like this.

```
SELECT summary.day, detail.`date`, detail.param
  FROM table AS detail
  JOIN (
          SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) AS day,
                 MAX(`date`) AS latest_timestamp_in_day
            FROM table
           WHERE `date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 366 DAY)
             AND `date` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
           GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))
       ) AS summary ON detail.`date` = summary.latest_timestamp_in_day
 ORDER BY summary.day DESC
```

Careful, though. the `DATETIME` arithmetic is done in the local time zone. This can lead to bizarre results on the days when local time changes from daylight savings to standard and back.

Notice that your column named `date` is in backticks. It's the same as a reserved word in MySQL's query language, so the backticks help disambiguate.

Here's a more detailed exposition of this business of grouping by date. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

Comment: tnx for detailed answer, trying it with sqlite
SELECT DATE(date(`date`,'unixepoch')) AS day,
       MAX(`date`) AS latest_timestamp_in_day
  FROM table
 WHERE `date` >= date('now', '-366 days')
   AND `date` < date(date())
 GROUP BY DATE(date(`date`))
 ORDER BY DATE(date(`date`)) DESC

but I think I lost something

Comment: need some time to play around

Comment: play around your solution a bit and solve it thanks
I need to read more about groups and methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `generator` to generate each year day and then join with your table:

```
SELECT r0 as start_day, MAX(date) 
(
 SELECT @row as r0, @row := @row + (24*60*60) as r1 FROM 
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all 
   select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all 
   select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) st1,
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all 
   select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all 
   select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) st2,
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 ) st3,
  (SELECT @row:=1420070400) st00  
) S
left outer join T
  on T.date BETWEEN S.r0 AND S.r1
where r1 <= 1451520000
```

Comment: tnx - I got this solution, but it is not optimised and trully makes too much queries - and that's why I'm here

Comment: Create an index on `date` and check performance in thousand of rows table. The [`sequence generator` is already tested](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75839) and my query is index friendly without row level functions. Please, don't talk to me about optimization.