# How many distinct values in a database at 5 min intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas, relational-database

Trying to build on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096096/count-how-many-entries-are-in-a-database-at-5-minute-intervals) I asked previously. I now need to count how many distinct devices are seen at each location rather than a count of overall devices because each device can be seen multiple times.

This can be either MySQL or Python Pandas solution.

[Sal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5544316/sal) previously answered the question for me.

The DB looks like this

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pi_id    | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name     | varchar(127) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| location | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| mac_id   | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rssi     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |  
| datetime | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Previous answer used is

```
SELECT concat( date_format(datetime,'%Y-%m-%d %k:')
             , lpad(floor(minute(datetime)/5)*5,2,'0')
             , ':00'
             ) datetime
     , location
     , count(1)
  FROM packet_locations
  GROUP BY date(datetime)
         , hour(datetime)
         , floor(minute(datetime)/5)
         , location;
```

Comment: Look into `COUNT(DISTINCT )`

Comment: Thank you, sometimes things are so obvious that they just pass you by.

Answer (score 0):

This can solved in pandas by lenght of distincts :

```
# to_dist_cols are the columns that combined will have repeated values removed.
len(df.drop_duplicates(to_dist_cols))
```

or in  MySql using `COUNT(DISTINCT)`